# Django staticfiles nesting

Tags: django, apache, deployment, filesystems

### Context

I am trying to setup a django continuous integration developpement system on a apache2 server via wsgi and Mercurial.

Setup seems to work fine, but with the changegroup hook, I run `python manage.py collectstatic --settings="sitename.settings" --noinput` to update the static files directory located in `/path/to/sitename/static/`.

### Problem

But with each run of the `python manage.py collectstatic --settings="sitename.settings" --noinput` command, my `/path/to/sitename/static/` directory gets a complete copy of the filesystem in `/path/to/sitename/`, thus leading in easy access to all code files, settings files, etc... with 5 run, i have 5 nested `/static/` in the static directory, eg. `static/`, `static/static/`, `static/static/static/` and so on...

This will become a real problem. I could just remove everything inside `static/` with each run, but some file permissions need to be preserved.

### Configuration used

At the moment, `DEBUG = True`
`/path/to/sitename/settings.py`:

```
# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/sitename/static/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/path/to/sitename/blog/static',
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

### Question

What am I missing? Is there something in the use of staticfile i did not understand?
Will I have other problems with this kind of solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATIC_ROOT) is where collectstatic will dump the files, and [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_DIRS) is where it will search for static files, note that this is *optional*. By default django will search for a `static` directory in all registered apps.

As far as duplication, as per the docs:

> Duplicate file names are by default resolved in a similar way to how
>   template resolution works: the file that is first found in one of the
>   specified locations will be used. If you're confused, the findstatic
>   command can help show you which files are found.

I didn't see where `STATIC_ROOT` is set in your settings, so I suspect you need to make sure these two are pointing at the right place.

The easiest way to use static files is to create a directory called `static` as a subdirectory of your application directory and leave `STATICFILES_DIRS` empty.

Comment: Thank you. I re-made settings.py from scratch, and it seems to work, althrough i don't really understand why. I will definitely read a bit more to make sure everything's ok.